# Can I recover files from corrupt Raspberry Pi sd?

Tags: linux, macos, raspberry-pi, corrupt

I have a Raspberry Pi sd card that I'd really hoping I can get files off.  I the sd card mounts in my Mac and I have a boot0 and RECOVERY under in the Mac devices menu. I can navigate the sd content on my Mac.

When I try to boot up the RPi with the sd card I get part way through the boot process then a flood of not normal text.  Then it ends with "Fixing recursive fault but reboot in needed!"  I had this twice now and the first time i waited about 5 minutes before shutting down.  This time I am leaving it for about 30 minutes in hopes that another message comes up and it says Fixed or something else.

If I can navigate the card on my Mac what should I do next assuming it is not going to boot?  Can I get to files on my Desktop?  It is one folder in particular I would love to recover.

The RPi is a 2 version B.

Comment: I am making a backup in case anyone says that as my first step.  `sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 of=~/Desktop/raspberrypi.dmg`

Comment: Have you looked at file recovery tools for the file system in use by the SD card?  Maybe mount it under a Linux VM?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why this is not more documented but I found a solution. I have Googled for a hour easy trying to find a solution and literally looked at 100 sites of what other did. Nothing worked for me.

Here is what I ended up doing.  I have another RPi around so I booted that up. Inserted the sd can into a reader.  plugged the reader into the other RPi and boom!  I have full access to the file system.  I accessed my Desktop folder and the www folder. Moved the files over for what I needed to recover.

This was crazy easy so I sure hope other find this post and try this first before all the crazy instructions out there.

Comment: Sir - you are my hero! I, too, had searched extensively and found nothing. I was facing the loss of several years of work (due to naive over-confidence). After reading your post, I dug through my box of USB drives, found the SD card reader, and I had my file system back! I'm in the process of recovering EVERYTHING! Thank you!!

Comment: BTW, my pi is a 3 B+ with a recent version of raspbian (not yet named raspberry pi os.